# If an apple is magnified to the size of the earth, then the atoms in the apple are approximately the size of the original apple

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, estimation, textbook-erratum, order-of-magnitude

Quoting from the [Feynman Lectures on Physics - Vol I](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_01.html):

> The atoms are 1 or $2 \times 10^{−8}\ \rm cm$ in radius. Now $10^{−8}\ \rm cm$ is called an angstrom (just as another name), so we say they are 1 or 2 angstroms (Å) in radius. Another way to remember their size is this: if an apple is magnified to the size of the earth, then the atoms in the apple are approximately the size of the original apple.

How does this hold true?

Let us assume the radius of an average apple is about $6\ \rm cm$ ($0.06\ \rm m$). The radius of earth is about $6371\ \rm km$ ($6371000\ \rm m$). Therefore, a $\frac{6371000\ \mathrm{m}}{0.06\ \mathrm{m}} = 106183333.33$ magnification, i.e., a magnification of about $10^{-8}$ times is required to magnify an apple to the size of the earth.

If we magnify an atom of size say 1 angstrom ($10^{-10}\ \rm m$) by $106183333.33$ times, we get $0.0106\ \rm m$ or $1.06\ \rm cm$ only. The atom has not been magnified to the size of the original apple. How does the quoted statement in the book hold good?

Comment: I would say that is is still a quite good approximation. It would be a great way to visualize it (for me) if I had any real sense of the size of the Earth.

Comment: 6 cm radius is an *enormous* apple, nearly a liter in volume.  That is more the size of a cantaloupe. If you go with a 3 cm radius (more the size of a tennis ball) the ratio comes out right within a factor of of better than 2.

Comment: It's really hard to comprehend the size of the whole Earth. When I wanted to impress my daughter with the smallness of atoms, I compared the number of atoms in one grain of sand with the number of sand grains it would take to make a pile as big as a certain mountain* that we can see from where we live. Of course, the accuracy of my claim depends very much on what you think the size of one "grain of sand" should be.

Comment: *we live in the Eastern U.S.A., so what we call "mountain", some people call "green hill."

Comment: Hopefully somebody with better search skills can find a reference, but I remember this sort of thing (accurate within three orders of magnitude) being referred to as "Feynman approximation".

Comment: @Ben51 and if you choose the Van der Waals radius of a carbon atom in the apple, you get 1.7 Å and you're basically spot on.

Comment: @l0b0 You're probably thinking of [Fermi problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem). (Often referred to as Fermi estimation or Fermi approximation.) Feynman probably used this often too, and he had better PR. ;)

Comment: A later author used a golf ball in his comparison.

Comment: Maybe it became a small variety called 'Crab apples'?

Comment: A nice read on Fermi estimation: https://what-if.xkcd.com/84/

Comment: @ben51, not necessarily that enormous. 400+ gr apples occur regularly to me, having 4 trees, especially with Bramley cooking apples; 400gr apples have a roughly 5cm radius (if spherical and specific density of 1 that 5-cm-radius apple weighs 524gr, but apples aren't perfectly round and float in water). So I have no problem with a 6-cm-apple.

Comment: "if a Smurf is magnified to the size of the earth, then the atoms in the Smurf are approximately the size of the original Smurf."

Comment: @Ben51 I think that the factor of two error here is not coincidental and someone simply confused diameter and radius of apple.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In "[back of the envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation)" calculations like this, all you can really do is look at orders of magnitude. As others have pointed out, not all apples have the same size, and not all atoms have the same "size". All we can then work with is orders of magnitude, so $1\ \rm cm$ and $6\ \rm cm$ (although many people in the comments are saying  $3\ \rm cm$) should  be considered to be the "same", since we could be dealing with apples and atoms of various sizes.

Indeed, if an apple's radius is on the order of $10^{-2}\ \rm m$, and if the Earth's radius is on the order of $10^6\ \rm m$, then our "conversion factor" (or as you say magnification factor) is on the order of $10^8$.

If our atom radius is on the order of one Angstrom, or $10^{-10}\ \rm m$, then applying our conversion factor when we blow up our apple, we get that the atom is on the order of $10^{-2}\ \rm m$, which is what we were trying to show in the first place.

You have to keep in mind that this is quoted as "a way to remember their size". Therefore, if we did not know the size of an atom, we could take the size of an apple, the size of the earth, and then use the derived $10^8$ factor to find that the estimated size of an atom is on the order of $10^{-10}\ \rm m$.$^*$

Feynman is *not* saying "Take any apple and blow it up to the size of the earth. You will find that the larger atoms are *exactly* the same size as the original apple". This is purely a memory tool, or it is also a way to describe the size of an atom using more familiar objects. Also the book even uses the word "approximately", so if you take all of this into account I would say the book is correct.

---

$^*$Although I have to admit, I tend to remember the size of an atom, and I can't seem to keep in my head the order of magnitude of the Earth's radius. So I might use this memory tool the other way around to remember that the size of the earth is about 8 orders of magnitude larger than an apple.

Comment: Speaking of mass comparisons, "a man is the geometric mean of an atom and the Sun".

Comment: And the book also mentions that atoms are 1-2 Angstrom, so he's already allowing for a factor of 2 error. OTOH, couldn't he have easily picked a smaller fruit like a plum or cherry? Just as familiar as an apple, but the ratio would be closer.

Comment: @Joker_vD Now we need to relate the energy gained from a man eating an apple to some sort of cosmic number... Something like "A man eating an apple is like a black hole eating ____" Although I wouldn't like to think about large scale GR while eating fruit :)

Comment: It's the internet, we need a way to relate another popular "masculine average" metric. Let's see, does the geometric mean between an AU and the Planck distance get us in the ballpark?

Comment: While you are at the 'size of earth' estimates, don't forget that the pole to equator surface distance is almost exactly 10,000km - how did that happen? ;-)

Comment: @PhilipOakley Our alien precursors only had Earth molds of that size when they made our planet. True fact. :)

Comment: @PhilipOakley how was original meter defined? ;)

Comment: @mathreadler The meter was part of an attempt by France to metricate everything, and one of those decimal division was that very given pole - equator distance. So the metre was originally that value exactly, but as surveys and precision increased we now get the modern value. A similar effect exists with the nautical mile, which originally was one minute of arc (as determined by the ship's sextant), but now has two additional definitions - the older Admiralty 6080 feet (for the knot) and the international nautical mile of 1,852 metres (those metres keep coming back!)

Comment: @PhilipOakley lol, an attempt? Basically no one relevant sticks to any other unit these days.

Comment: @mathreadler All these 'units' are still in use in various places (I've personally needed to clarify the Nm value a number of times). There are nice stories about the cartographers stealing more land from the French map than any foreign army had done (and their best estimate of the 'metre' was slightly undersized relative to the circumference)

Answer (score 24):

Your question starts out with questioning whether the numbers match up very well, and then you proceed to throw away all the accuracy in your numbers to demonstrate that they don't.

While throwing away accuracy in-favor of considering just the orders of magnitude is useful for approximating (and is what the other answers are explaining is okay), it turns out if you just run the numbers through as-written, you actually get a pretty accurate correspondence.

Taking atomic radius as $1.5 \times 10^{-10}~\text{m}$ (average of range given above) and the radius of Earth as $6371000~\text{m}$ (given above), the correspondence is exact when the radius of the object is $\approx 30.91~\text{mm}$ (or diameter $61.83~\text{mm}$).  The size of an apple varies by climate, variety, and harvest time, but this figure is consistent with an ordinary "175-grade" apple, albeit most apples sold in the United States are slightly larger.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now. If $ x $ is the radius of the apple, then $ \frac{6371000}{x} = \frac{x}{1.5 \times 10^{-10}} $ indeed leads to $ x = 0.03091 $ or $ 30.91 $ mm.

Answer (score 9):

When dealing with such orders of magnitude, a factor of 6 does not greatly affect the overall picture. Furthermore, note that apples have radii that are often smaller than $6$ cm (see for instance [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4382048/)). If we take an apple with a radius of $3$ cm and an atom with a radius of $2$ angstrom, the "Feynman comparison" (as per your numbers) comes out to be fairly good.

Comment: I take issue with "a factor of 6 can easily be disregarded". An order of magnitude is purposefully vague, but in all common definitions (just the exponent in the a*10^b notation, all values within (0.5x, 5x] and so on) the order changes for most values if you multiply or divide by 6.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. In fact, the term "disregard" might be a bit too strong. I'll reword the answer so as to "weaken" the first sentence. Cheers!

Comment: I would also point out that the OP is running fast and loose with precision.  That 106,183,333.33 number comes from two values precise to maybe 1.5 and 4 digits, so the most you can really say is that the magnification is about 1.1E8 (1.1 x 10 ^ 8).  Suddenly the apple gets a little bigger.

Answer (score 5):

Let's test that by figuring out the size of an atom by that comparison.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple) says:

> Commercial growers aim to produce an apple that is 2 3⁄4 to 3 1⁄4 in (7.0 to 8.3 cm) in diameter, due to market preference.

So we use an average radius of $3.825~\text{cm}$ or $0.03825~\text{m}$ and the radius of the earth of $6371000~\text{m}$ for the calculation.

Then the radius of an atom is calculated as:
$$
r_{atom} = \frac{r_{apple}^2}{r_{earth}} = \frac{0.03825^2~\text{m}^2}{6371000~\text{m}}
$$

As a result we get  $2.296 \times 10^{-10}~\text{m}$ which is fairly close.